# How can I read all answers on Quora without having to register?

Tags: registration, quora

Quora only shows its first answer on a question's page, the rest gets blurred out.

It then asks the user to register to read all the answers. I really do not like such bullying tactics and I hence will never register.

Yet before I blacklist Quora entirely from my Google searches, I wonder if there was a way to read all the answers without having to register.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Add the get parameter

```
?share=1
```

at the end of the question's URL, and all the answers will show. You have to set it only once per browser session.

I have built a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/all-answers-for-quora/oibecpjfbcfhiijpppnjinnnoldjmiac) to automate on pre-load. ([It's also open source.](https://github.com/k0pernikus/allAnswersForQuora))

Comment: It does not work with log pages like https://www.quora.com/log/revision/171443788?share=1 alas.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore :/

Comment: @Freedo untrue, I still observe the functionality.

Comment: The tag "?share=1" doesn't seem to work anymore -- at least, not when appending it to answer posts by specific users, e.g. https://www.quora.com/What-is-it-like-to-be-a-hostage-negotiator/answer/Rick-Bruno-1?share=1. Is there another way to view specific answer posts without signing in?

Answer (score 5):

I would add to k0pernikus's great answer that the `?share=1` is [officially supported and promoted by Quora](https://blog.quora.com/Making-Sharing-Better) (it is not  some ephemeral hack that would go against their policies):

> [Marc Bodnick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Bodnick) (Leads Quora business & community teams, executive at Quora): 
> Open any Quora URL. If you come across a Quora link anywhere and you
>   want to read it without being asked to join Quora, you can add the
>   text "?share=1" to the end of the URL. Example:
>   http://www.quora.com/Hostage-Situations/What-does-it-feel-like-to-be-a-hostage-negotiator?share=1

You can use the Google Chrome extension [Block Quora Login Popup](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-quora-login-popup/fkbnfnaikpdihahjljbigedkangbieih?hl=en-US) too.

Comment: The tag "?share=1" doesn't seem to work anymore -- at least, not when appending it to answer posts by specific users, e.g. https://www.quora.com/What-is-it-like-to-be-a-hostage-negotiator/answer/Rick-Bruno-1?share=1. Is there another way to view specific answer posts by users without signing in?

Answer (score 0):

[Quora Unblocker](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/5224-quora-unblocker) userscript automatically adds `?share=1` at the end of every Quora URL.
[How to install user scripts](https://greasyfork.org/en/help/installing-user-scripts)