# See the author of a question on Quora (without logging in)

Tags: quora

I want to see who asked a question on Quora. The question page shows the author of each answer (or shows “Anonymous”), the author of each comment, even the names of the voters… but there's no indication of the author of the question!

I don't have a Quora account.

Comment: Related: [How can I read all answers on Quora without having to register?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43179/how-can-i-read-all-answers-on-quora-without-having-to-register) (answer: `?share=1`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Adam D'Angelo](http://www.quora.com/Adam-DAngelo) via [On Quora, why can't I see the original author on the question page (though I can in my homepage feed)?](http://www.quora.com/Quora/On-Quora-why-cant-I-see-the-original-author-on-the-question-page-though-I-can-in-my-homepage-feed?share=1)

> We're trying to prevent people from answering the person rather than answering the question by keeping the asker off the question page.
>
> If you're on a question page and you want to find out who added it first, you can click through to the "All Changes" link under the question details.

The “All Changes” link doesn't appear anywhere if you aren't logged in, but the URL is simple to construct (thanks to [Michael Hampton](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/22277/michael-hampton) for finding this): add `/log` to the question URL, e.g.
http://www.quora.com/Quora/On-Quora-why-cant-I-see-the-original-author-on-the-question-page-though-I-can-in-my-homepage-feed/log?share=1 Scroll to the bottom (the page loads dynamically, so you may have to scroll down multiple times) to see “Question added by …”.

Comment: Or ask me, as I am usually logged in. @MichaelHampton very nicely done! I new about the `?share=1` workaround, but never thought of appending it to other Quora URLS, only to a question and all (not just the top) associated answers. Thank you!