# Given a particular Question on Quora, how to find as to who has posted the Question?

Tags: quora

How do we find a person behind the question, (obviously) if it was not posted as Anonymous.

Comment: possible duplicate of [See the author of a question on Quora (without logging in)](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46646/see-the-author-of-a-question-on-quora-without-logging-in)

Comment: The question you linked focuses on "(without logging in)", so the answer is a bit different (it is tedious to add `/log` manually all the time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Latest activity and scroll down. E.g. https://www.quora.com/Chess/Could-a-computer-consistently-beat-Magnus-Carlsen-at-chess:

[image]

then scroll down:
[image]